# Как заменить модель в three js react?

Tags: reactjs, three.js

Основной код работы со сценой помещен в useEffect, туда же приходит массив объектов, которые нужно отобразить на сцене. Методом перебора я добавляю их на сцену. Но при изменении значений в массиве объектов, мне рисуется отдельная сцена, а я хочу менять выбранную модель и вместо нее загружать новую. Help please)

```
 const Test = ({ project }) => {
  const { surfaces } = project;


  const ref = useRef();
   useEffect(() => {
    main();

    function main() {
      initM();
      animate();
    }

    function initM() {
      initScene(); 
      initCamera(); 
      initLights(); 
      initRenderer();
      initControls();
      addObjectsFromStore();
      initDragControls();
    
      ref.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }
    // добавляем модели
    function addObjectsFromStore() {
      surfaces.map((el) => {
        if (el.type === "model") {
          let root;
          const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
          gltfLoader.load(`${el.url}`, (gltf) => {
            root = gltf.scene;
            root.position.set(el.dots.x, el.dots.y, el.dots.z);
            root.userData.name = el.name;

            root.userData.id = el.id;
            root.userData.currentPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
            root.userData.startPosition = {
              x: el.dots.x,
              y: el.dots.y,
              z: el.dots.z,
            };
            combinePartsOfModel(root);
          });
        }
        return el;
      });
    }
// эта функция должна срабатывать при изменении массива surfaces где лежат актуальные модели

    function replaceModel(prevModel, nextModel) {
     
      const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
      gltfLoader.load(`${nextModel.url}`, (gltf) => {
        let root = gltf.scene;
        root.position.x = 2;
        root.position.y = 0.7;
        root.position.z = 3;

        scene.add(root);
        scene.remove(prevModel);
       
        root.userData.currentPosition = new THREE.Vector3();

      });
    }
    
   
    function initControls() {
      orbit = new OrbitControls(cameraPersp, renderer.domElement);
      orbit.update();
      orbit.addEventListener("change", render);
    }
  

    
    function initRenderer() {
      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    
      renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
      renderer.shadowMapSort = true;
    }

    function initControls() {
      orbit = new OrbitControls(cameraPersp, renderer.domElement);
      orbit.update();
      orbit.addEventListener("change", render);
    }

    function render() {
      renderer.render(scene, cameraPersp);
    }

    function animate() {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      render();
    }
    return () => {
      // Callback to cleanup three js, cancel animationFrame, etc
    };
  },[]);


  return (
    <>
      <div ref={ref} />
    </>
  );
};
```